# Android: infinite scroll with rx-java using repeatWhen, takeUntil and filter with retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am using Retrofit 2.2 with RxJava.
The pagination works like this: I get the first batch of data, I have to request the second batch of data with the same params except one which is the lastUpdated date and then if I get empty or the same batch of data it means there are no more items. I have found this great article https://medium.com/@v.danylo/server-polling-and-retrying-failed-operations-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-8bcc7e641a5a#.40aeibaja on how to do it. So my code is:

```
private Observable<Integer> syncDataPoints(final String baseUrl, final String apiKey,
        final long surveyGroupId) {
    final List<ApiDataPoint> lastBatch = new ArrayList<>();
    Timber.d("start syncDataPoints");
    return loadAndSave(baseUrl, apiKey, surveyGroupId, lastBatch)
            .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(final Observable<? extends Void> observable) {
                    Timber.d("Calling repeatWhen");
                    return observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            })
            .takeUntil(new Func1<List<ApiDataPoint>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<ApiDataPoint> apiDataPoints) {
                    boolean done = apiDataPoints.isEmpty();
                    if (done) {
                        Timber.d("takeUntil : finished");
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("takeUntil : will query again");
                    }
                    return done;
                }
            })
            .filter(new Func1<List<ApiDataPoint>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<ApiDataPoint> apiDataPoints) {
                    boolean unfiltered = apiDataPoints.isEmpty();
                    if (unfiltered) {
                        Timber.d("filtered");
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("not filtered");
                    }
                    return unfiltered;
                }
            }).map(new Func1<List<ApiDataPoint>, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(List<ApiDataPoint> apiDataPoints) {
                    Timber.d("Finished polling server");
                    return 0;
                }
            });
}

private Observable<List<ApiDataPoint>> loadAndSave(final String baseUrl, final String apiKey,
        final long surveyGroupId, final List<ApiDataPoint> lastBatch) {
    return loadNewDataPoints(baseUrl, apiKey, surveyGroupId)
            .concatMap(new Func1<ApiLocaleResult, Observable<List<ApiDataPoint>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<ApiDataPoint>> call(ApiLocaleResult apiLocaleResult) {
                    return saveToDataBase(apiLocaleResult, lastBatch);
                }
            });
}


private Observable<ApiLocaleResult> loadNewDataPoints(final String baseUrl, final String apiKey,
        final long surveyGroupId) {
    Timber.d("loadNewDataPoints");

    return Observable.just(true).concatMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<ApiLocaleResult>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ApiLocaleResult> call(Object o) {
            Timber.d("loadNewDataPoints call");
            return restApi
                    .loadNewDataPoints(baseUrl, apiKey, surveyGroupId,
                            getSyncedTime(surveyGroupId));
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see the interesting method is `loadNewDataPoint`s and I want it to be called until there are no more datapoints. As you can see `Observable.just(true).concatMap` is a hack because if I remove this concat map the  `restApi.loadNewDataPoints(....)` does not get called although in the logs I can see that the api does get called but with the same old params and of course it returns the same results as the first time so syncing stops, saveToDataBase does get called fine. With my hack it works but I want to understand why it does not work the other way and also if there is a better way to do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So, I've written this kind of APIs (it's called Keyset Pagination) and implemented Rx clients against them.

This is one of the cases where BehaviorSubjects are useful:

```
S initialState = null;
BehaviorProcessor<T> subject = BehaviorProcessor.createDefault(initialState);
return subject
  .flatMap(state -> getNextElements(state).singleOrError().toFlowable(), Pair::of, 1)
  .serialize()
  .flatMap(stateValuePair -> {
      S state = stateValuePair.getLeft();
      R retrievedValue = stateValuePair.getRight();
      if(isEmpty(retrievedValue)) {
         subject.onComplete();
         return Flowable.empty();
      } else {
         subject.onNext(getNextState(state, retrievedValue));
         return Flowable.just(retrievedValue);
      }
    }
   .doOnUnsubscribe(subject::onCompleted)
   .map(value -> ...)
```

Here

- `getNextElement` performs the network call based on a state and returns a reactive stream with a single value
- `isEmpty` determines whether the returned value is empty indicating end of elements
- `getNextState` combines the passed-in state with the retrieved value to determine the next state for `getNextElement`.

It will work correctly if an error occurs (it will be propagated) and if you unsubscribe before the end (queries will get terminated).

Of course, in your specific case these don't need to be separate methods or complex types.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about keyset pagination which I have searched and it seems like way better than offset http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset. Also thanks for the code I will try this, I have not used Flowables yet. What do you mean by "these don't need to be separate methods or complex types"?

Comment: I mean that the code segment is more like pseudocode - you could have f.e `if(retrievedValue.getList().isEmpty())`. Also, you could just as well use Observables, but then you'll lose backpressure.