# RXJava + Retrofit. Repeat request every n seconds

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, repeat

The request is repeated every n seconds after a successful response from the server. But there is a field in the query time, which changes the query itself. RepeatWhen - not suitable for this reason. Tell me, how can I solve this problem? Thank)

```
  AtomicBoolean onComplete = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .compose(rxSchedulersAbs.getIOToMainTransformer())
                .map(new Func1<Long, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> call(Long tick) {
                        if (onComplete.get()) {
                            onComplete.set(false);
                            return requestCreator.getSyncMessage();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }).map(sync -> {
            if (sync != null)
                onComplete.set(true);
            return sync;
        }).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the *frequency* of the requests based on what the server sends back, I would suggest using a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> delayObs = BehaviorSubject.create(3);
delayObs
.serialize()
.flatMap(delay -> Observable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
.flatMap(dummy -> requestCreator.getSyncMessage())
.onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
   if(e instanceof IOException) {
     delayObs.onNext(3);
     return Observable.empty();
   } else {
     return Observable.error(e);
   }
}
.doOnNext(sync -> {
    if(sync == null) {
      delayObs.onComplete();
    } else {
      delayObs.onNext(getNextInterval(sync));
    }
}
.compose(rxSchedulersAbs.getIOToMainTransformer())
.subscribe();
```

If, on the other hand, you need to change the request that is made with data from the response you gust received, [this might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537203/android-infinite-scroll-with-rx-java-using-repeatwhen-takeuntil-and-filter-wit/42541317#42541317).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The difficulty is that I need to organize a pooling every 3 seconds, but one of the fields changes in the query. Also it is required to check whether the last request was successful and add 3 seconds from it